# Can’t understand the pressure acting on an object when immersed in fluid (Static fluid)

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I can’t comprehend two contradictory points regarding the pressure acting on an object immersed in a fluid, as discussed in the Static Fluids section, perhaps because I’m missing on something and I need your kind guidance.

- At the beginning of the chapter (Chapter 10 Giancoli Physics), it said that “Pressure is the same in every direction in a non-moving fluid at a given depth”.
- Later in the same chapter, “Archimedes Principle”, it said that “pressure increases with depth. Thus the upward pressure on the bottom surface of a submerged object is greater than the downward pressure on its top surface”. And this is the basis of the buoyant force.
- How come can such a statement be valid with respect to the first
  point that says pressure is equal in all sides?

Comment: The meaning of "pressure is same everywhere" is only valid in pressure at horizontal level at some constant depth from the surface, in a liquid pressure changes with depth which is equal to $P = ρgh$ in this equation we can see that pressure is depending upon the depth of the immersed object or any point at depth $h$. The complete and correct statement must be "until and unless the fluid is at the rest the pressure is same horizontally at every point in that line"

Comment: Makes sense now, sometimes the wording in books is somewhat ambiguous. Thanks for the clarification.